# client_side_validation and devise Gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When I am installing client_side_validation in my project its giving error

```
ArgumentError in Devise::Sessions#new
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
in 
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Its working fine if I am removing gem client_side_valiation from my gem file. I tried searching on stackoverflow but not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

And you can find useful info here:
[Client side validations with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310477/client-side-validations-with-devise)